# when we send email with job and queue error occur

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

[when send emails shows these error][1]`ReflectionException Method App\Mail\Newsletter::__invoke() does not exist`

[these is my controlle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei8ga.png)`dispatch(new Newsletter($emailSubject,$emailBody,$arrayEmails));`
[these is my email class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFzXg.png)`public function build() { return $this->view('emails.newsletter')->subject($this->emailSubject)->with(['msg'=> $this->emailBody]); }`
[these is my jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfbZu.png) `public function handle() { $email = new Newsletter($this->emailSubject,$this->emailBody,$this->arrayEmails); Mail::to($this->arrayEmails)->send($email); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you create a job that in turn create and send the email object.

However, in the controller, you are not dispatching the job, you are dispatch the email object. And the email object doesn't contain either a `handle` or `__invoke` method so you see the error message.

The solution is to dispatch the job instead of the email.

This design is indeed unnecessary. Pls have a look at [Mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail), create a queued mailable, and just send it.